# How to iterate over array with custom type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I declared type:

```
 export interface Type{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Now I want iterate over array of this type:

```
for(var t of types) // types = Type[]
{
  console.log(t.id);
}
```

I get error:

> D:/Google/services/test.service.ts (33,20): Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Type'.

Comment: I don't see any bug in that code. Are you sure that Type in both snippets are the same interface?

Comment: Fixed. I restart ng serve and everything works.

Comment: remove the question then

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I want do it, but I can't,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restart server.

Some Angular error. After restart ng serve, everythings works.

Answer (score 0):

HI you can do alternative way using  **forEach**

```
types.forEach(element => {
             console.log(element.id)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the iteration variable  t

```
for(var t of types){}
```

use like this

```
var i =0, len= types.length;
for(;i<len; i++){
      Console.log(types[i]);
 }
```